# Create Empty element using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am unable to figure it out how to build below XML using XSLT 1.0

```
<values>
      <field name="abc"></field>
      <field name="nch"></field>
</values>
```

there should not be any space between elements start and end tag.
Kindly help me as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Saxon you have to change the **output method** to "**html**".

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <values>
      <field name="abc"></field>
      <field name="nch"></field>
    </values>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here´s a workearound that works for vs2010.

Example 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <values>
      <field name="abc">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(' ',' ')"/>
      </field>
      <field name="nch">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(' ',' ')"/>
      </field>
    </values>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="values">
      <xsl:element name="filed">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">abc</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(' ',' ')"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="filed">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">nch</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(' ',' ')"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<values>
  <filed name="abc"></filed>
  <filed name="nch"></filed>
</values>
```

Comment: Not producing the wanted result with Saxon.

Comment: thanks for your response but none of these is working for me.It gives same out in both examples.

Comment: Yes you´r right. I have tested it with saxon and that´s not the same output as i had in vs2010. If you use saxon you have to change the output method to "html" instead of "xml".

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.but in my scenario i have to stick with output method to XML.i cant use HTML.so,just let me know if you have any workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `<x></x>` and `<x/>` is purely lexical and generally cannot be controlled by the XSLT processor, because the final output is performed by the Serializer.

With some XSLT processors (using their built-in serializers), it may be possible to output the full form of an empty element. However, with other processors, such as Saxon, this isn't (easily) possible.

Comment: i am using xalan xslt processor.is this possible in xalan?

Comment: @user1904426, Sorry, I haven't Xalan installed. You may try something like `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:value-of select="$someEmptyVariable"/></xsl:copy>`